# How to import a local image into a react app

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to import an image from my desktop into react however I am having difficulty doing so,

Here is the code I have tried to use:

```
<img className = "header_logo"src='file:///C:/myFileDestination' alt ="logo"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

How to import an image in React: (google is your friend)

```
import headerLogo from '../../assets/header-logo.svg';

...

<div className="header-logo">
    <img src={headerLogo} alt='logo' />
</div>
```

Comment: Great response.  Additional note: `className = "header_logo"src=` is a syntax error,  and hard-coding a path in the app (e.g. `src='file:///C:/myFileDestination'`) is a Mortal Sin...